# Download files via id using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have over 100 articles. Each article has a different PDF file attached. There's a form where a user must filled and gets redirected to a thank you page. The code is below.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://example.com/thankyou';
}, false );
```

In the above code, I would like to add the code below so that it triggers the download. How can I combine this two codes?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download a").trigger("click");
});
```

The article in HTML format:

```
<p>Content goes here</p>
<p id="download"><a href="https://example.com/path/file.pdf">Download</a></p>
```

If there's a better way, please suggest.

Comment: How does the form relate to the link to the article? Does the link become available after the form is submitted? Are the form and the link on the same page? The context for your question is not clear at all. We need more info i think, before we can give a proper answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, the form is a widget which is available in every article. The download PDF file is in the article. However, the file names are different. The ID will be constant.

Comment: so after the form is submitted you want to automatically initiate the download, and also redirect them to the thankyou page, is that correct?

Comment: @ADyson Yes. Correct.

Comment: Ok. If the answer below doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll try and come up with another way

Comment: @ADyson It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

### Pass in a get parameter.

Since you're reloading a new page, you should pass along a get parameter to indicate the download should start.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://example.com/thankyou?download';
}, false );
```

Then on your page that does have the download file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.search.includes("download")){
    $("#download a").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

If you had a list on a single page, you could pass an argument in the download parameter
`?download="1234.zip"` and use that as your target. Please be careful if you use this method so you don't open yourself up to JS injection.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: It isn't working. It ended up in `https://example.com/thankyou?download` but the download was never triggered.

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure that the `if (window.location.search.includes("download"))` was accurate. I would check there first.